# Clear the cache on an AJAX load when running a PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, caching

I've got a page which is loaded via AJAX in WordPress. The image (there's only one per page) and content of the page are cached, as is usual. The image is auto-generated using a PHP function.

I've seen lots of solutions for *never* caching the loaded content - usually appending a date time or random number to the end of the URL when loading.

However, usually, I'd want the results to be cached - it saves time and memory, of course.

The image for each page is generated automatically using the following code whenever the page is saved or a new user is added to the page as post meta:

```
function group_thumbnail($post_id) {

        // Generates a composite thumbnail, a la Spotify playlists, to use in the group layout.
        global $pagenow;

        if(get_post_type($post_id)=='group' && $pagenow != 'post-new.php' && $_GET['action']!='trash')  : // Post new has to be excluded, or it tries to do this with nothing in it.

                $user_portraits = array();
                if(!empty($_POST['wpcf']['allowed-users'])) :
                    $allowed_users = $_POST['wpcf']['allowed-users']; // For the back end
                else : 
                    $allowed_users = get_post_meta($post_id,'wpcf-allowed-users',false); // For the front end
                endif;

                $group_size = count($allowed_users);

                if($group_size < 4) : $limit=1; $row_size = 1; endif;
                if($group_size >= 4 && $group_size < 9) : $limit=4; $row_size = 2; endif;
                if($group_size >= 9 && $group_size < 16) : $limit=9; $row_size = 3; endif;
                if($group_size >= 16) : $limit=16; $row_size = 4; endif;
                $square_size = 200/$row_size;
                foreach ($allowed_users as $u_id) :
                    $u_portrait=get_user_meta($u_id, 'wpcf-portrait', true); 
                    $u_file = imagecreatefromjpeg($u_portrait);
                    $user_portraits[] = $u_file;
                endforeach;
                $group_image = imagecreatetruecolor ( 200 , 200 );
                $postion = array('x'=>0,'y'=>0);
                for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++) :    
                    if($i % $row_size == 0 && $i<>0) : 
                        $postion['x']=0;
                        $postion['y']+=$square_size;
                    endif;  

                    imagecopyresized($group_image,$user_portraits[$i],$postion['x'],$postion['y'],0,0,$square_size,$square_size,180,180);
                    imagedestroy($user_portraits[$i]);
                    $postion['x']+=$square_size;
                endfor;         
                // Output and free from memory
                imagejpeg($group_image,get_template_directory().'/img/groups/'.$post_id.'.jpg',60);
                imagedestroy($group_image);
            endif;

    }
```

While the image is updating correctly (I can see it in the folder), when the page is loaded via AJAX, the old image is still cached.

Is there a way of *only* clearing the cache when this function triggers?

Comment: _“Is there a way of only clearing the cache when this function triggers?”_ – no, there is not. How the browser treats a resource when it comes to caching, is mainly dependent on the caching headers it received the _last_ time it requested that resource. Now, unless you have a time machine, you can not change that retroactively.

Comment: If I had a time machine, caching would be the furthest thing from my mind.